# Python : Remove everything after a specific character (,)

Tags: python, character

I have millions of lines inside a file (9GB)(can't opened by Notepad++) and i want to remove all the words after a specific characters. (,)

Example of line :

data1,data2,data3,data4

I want to keep the (data1) and delete everything else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try? What did not work? Please post your code.

Comment: do you want to remove it from the file? or just remove it from the line after you read in the data ?

Comment: You can use Python's `split()` function to split strings at a particular character. Your task can be accomplished with a simple one-liner, so open a Python prompt and start experimenting with a single line of data. Once you're happy with it, iterate through your data file one line at a time and apply the one-liner.

Comment: @SrinivasSuresh remove it from the file please.

Comment: @DyZ i wanted to try notepad++ search a replace (,.*) but it seem that the file is too large. that why i want a simple python code please.

Comment: SO is not a code-writing service. You have to demonstrate substantial research effort before posting a question here.

Comment: create a list to hold lines - open the file in read mode - for each line in the file - if ',' in line split on ',' and append the 0th element to the holding list otherwise append line to holding list - open the file for writing - for each element in the holding list write to the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use split on each line to split the line on the first comma and only write out the left part of the split:

For example:

```
with open('input.txt') as infile:
    with open('output.txt','w') as outfile:
        for line in infile.readline():
            outfile.write(line.strip().split(",",1)[0]+"\n")
```